# Speed up global access to server (Apache, MySQL and Fileserver)

Tags: mysql, apache, latency, fileserver

Today i have a NAS server acting webserver, MySQL and fileserver in Europe, but now i also need it to be accessable from US. My problem is that it is very slow do to the latency. What can i do to make this better - can i somehow sync two NAS stations, or do you suggest i go for the cloud (if this is the case, then what setup are you suggesting)

The NAS server is a Synology and is using Apache and MySQL

I have already tried to setup a VPN connection, but this is not making things faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readonly web pages, have web servers and Slaves in all general locations (eg, 1+ in US, 1+ in Europe).  Such pages will render promptly.

If a web page needs to write, that is messier, since at least one "hop across the pond" is required for at least some of the users.  One hop is at least 150ms, in my experience.

If you use Master-Slave, then those who are far from the Master will need to connect and do at least one write.  (2 hops).

If you use a WAN deployment of Galera (PXC, MariaDB 10), there will, in theory, be only 1 hop per transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the scale of the project. If it is a large project the best thing you could do is install the Webserver, SQL server and Fileserver on the same LAN. I assume the only thing that needs to be facing outwards is the Webserver. If it is small, then the best thing to do would be to have them all on the same server.

Aside from this one of the best things you can do with SQL servers is to upgrade their RAM. For a Fileserver upgrade its HDD/RAID. There won't be a huge performance increase but its the only thing you can do.

Comment: It is not the speed of the website / database that is the problem. It is the latency do to the delay on the internet

Comment: Yes, so if all services are on the same LAN/PC then you greatly reduce the "hops" and latency.

Comment: Yes, but how to ensure that it is the same data you are accessing? - then you will have to doublicate the data right?

Comment: Why complicate the issue? Move the SQL and File servers. Is this an option?

Comment: No, there will be users in both Europe and US

Comment: So the Web server isn't performing very well? add another Web server to your Europe LAN. have US users access the other server. Your other options are to upgrade the Web server to something faster or make your code run faster.

Comment: doveyg, thanks for your help, but your answers really don't help me. It is the delay and latency on the internet that is causing the issues - NOT the performance on the server...

Comment: If its performing fine why do you need the two servers? the only reason i can think of to cluster a web service is if you were getting too much traffic or are anticipating an increase in traffic. I can ping the other side of the world in ~500ms that bottleneck will always be there, no magic exists to circumvent that. the best solution is to use one server. unless its overloaded...